# embedded Lua C++ : how can i load multiple lua modules from C++ side

Tags: c++, module, lua, loading

in my application I would like to load a base library in Lua before loading the lua script.

example:

testLib.lua

```
A = 5
B = 6

function foo(a,b)
    return a+b
end
```

test.lua

```
c = foo(A,B)
```

In my C++ module I would like to do something like this

```
// load the lib 
luaL_loadbuffer(L, libText, libSize, "testLib");
// run it so that the globals are known
lua_pcall(L,0,0,0);
// load the main script that uses the lib function and variables
luaL_loadbuffer(L, progText, progSize, "testLib");
// run it
lua_pcall(L,0,0,0);
```

here I get an error that the function 'foo' is not known

Is there a way to load multiple Lua modules on the same lua state ?

thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 0):

you would need to bind the function foo first.

http://lua-users.org/wiki/BindingCodeToLua

shows how to do it on an example where they bind c math functions

Comment: Hi Markus,thanks for the replay. The problem is , I do not want to re compile C++ module. The scripts are located on the SD card. So binding the functions is no option.